# Add delay to ng-bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: ng-bootstrap

In contrast to the Bootstrap tooltip, the ng-bootstrap Tooltip for Angular 2 at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip has no provision for a delay, so the tooltip pops up immediately.

I see an issue about this 'ngbTooltip: add new option "delay"' at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1052 but it is listed as "No one assigned".

Is there a workaround that could be applied to simple code like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/tooltip/demos/basic/plnkr.html to add a delay?

Is there some way of assessing whether a delay capacity is likely to be added to ngbTooltip?

Comment: I found an example at https://embed.plnkr.co/gjnRxnmk0IqG0gSVlCQg/ that purports to add a delay to an Angular 2 Bootstrap tooltip, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this comment](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1052#issuecomment-332294381), you can achieve it with pure css:

```
.tooltip > div {
  animation-name: delayedFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s; /* Adjust this duration */
}

@Keyframes delayedFadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  75% {opacity: 0;} /* Set this to 99% for no fade-in. */
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

If you want to make it optional, you can define another class such as `.delayed`:

```
.delayed.tooltip > div {
  animation-name: delayedFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s; /* Adjust this duration */
}

@Keyframes delayedFadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  75% {opacity: 0;} /* Set this to 99% for no fade-in. */
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work with or without the container attribute.  I am assuming this can be set in the global css file.

Comment: Yeah, you can just put it in the global style. If you want to make it optional, you can define another class. Check my edit.

Comment: This works, either as written, in the global styles.css, or in the relevant TypeScript files, using "/deep/ .tooltip".  It seems to work with or without the ">div", I don't know what div is referencing.  This is great.  Thanks.  Marking as answer.

Comment: hey, I want this same functionality but for fadeout...can you help...I want 1 sec fadeout delay for tooltip...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub feature request at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1052 asking for adding delay to ngbTooltip, but so far there is no action on this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use S.alems code and make tooltips appearing a little longer (make a delay before appear) everytime with no using javascript or adding and removing classes
you need to just use it like this:

```
.tooltip.bottom.in.fade{
animation-name: delayedFadeIn;
animation-duration: 1.1s; /* Adjust this duration */
}

@Keyframes delayedFadeIn {
 0% {opacity: 0;}
 75% {opacity: 0;} /* Set this to 99% for no fade-in. */
 100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

I did even create account to post this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.1.0 there is an option to set `openDelay` and `closeDelay`. See its [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api).

Values are in ms so to set the open delay to 1 second and close delay to 2 seconds use following code:

```
<span 
  ngbtooltip="my tooltip text" 
  openDelay="1000" 
  closeDelay="2000">
</span>
```